# Can I use voice command to do melacha on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat

Let's say I implant a voice recognizer in a stove or oven to activate the device through voice recognition. Does that count as doing a masseh melachah?

Comment: FYI see this article on the gramma switch http://www.zomet.org.il/Eng/?CategoryID=249&ArticleID=101&Page=1&SearchParam=

Comment: The GRAMA switch is different in reguarding that the person is doing a "masseh" my question is wether speaking into a voice recognizer is counted as a masseh